# PagedListPager customise paging links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, nuget-package

I'm using the following package to do paging in ASP.NET MVC

https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

This is wokring great, however I'd like to be able to add a extra HTML5 data attribute to the pager links. Simply which contains the page number of the link.

For example:

```
<a href="admin/demo/userlist" data-page-no="1">1</a> <a href="admin/demo/userlist" data-page-no="2">2</a> etc etc
```

But I'm struggling to do this and can only get the page number into the URL.

Can anyone help? I would have thought this would have been a common and useful feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorted with some help from Troy, working perfect now :)

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => "admin/demo/userlist", new PagedListRenderOptions { FunctionToTransformEachPageLink = (liTag, aTag) => { aTag.Attributes.Add("data-page-no", aTag.InnerHtml); liTag.InnerHtml = aTag.ToString(); return liTag; } })
```

Answer (score 2):

Short deadline hack.  I tried something similar, but if the inner HTML for the hyperlink is an ellipse or some other special character, it didn't quite work.

```
               FunctionToTransformEachPageLink = (li, a) =>
               {
                   if (a.Attributes.ContainsKey("href"))
                   {
                       Uri uri;
                       if (Uri.TryCreate("http://temp.org/" + a.Attributes["href"], UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
                       {
                           var qs = uri.Query;
                           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(qs))
                           {
                               var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs);
                               var page = nvc["page"];
                               a.MergeAttribute("data-page", page);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       int page;
                       if (int.TryParse(a.InnerHtml, out page))
                           a.MergeAttribute("data-page", page.ToString());
                   }

                   li.InnerHtml = a.ToString();
                   return li;
               }
```

"FunctionToTransformEachPageLink" should include the current page as a delegate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using "latest" 8.0.7 nuget `X.PagedListMvc.Core` the `FunctionToTransformEachPageLink`  delegate is adding and additional element when passing return value. So if you return `liTag` the page number link will be doubled. The working code is below, just returning an empty tag builder:

```
FunctionToTransformEachPageLink = (TagBuilder liTag, TagBuilder aTag) =>
        {
            var ret = new TagBuilder("text");

            aTag.Attributes.Add("data-otf-target", "#page-wrapper");

            liTag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(aTag);

            return ret;
        },
```

If anyone has a better solution please edit this post.